# Alias is already in use by the “--collection” option and cannot be used by the “--change-detection” option

Tags: angular

I'm getting this error by executing `ng g c user`, but it also happens with `ng generate component` and I don't understand i need a help:

> The "c" alias is already in use by the "--collection" option and cannot be used by the "--change-detection" option. Please use a different alias.

Comment: Please enlarge your questions with some code you have tried. It's hard to help you with few information of your context. But I would say that you have defined 2 times the 'c' short alias, one time for '--collection' and another for '--change-detection'. you may use -d for the second

Comment: I don't know in what code it related so i don't post any code ng g c work the last day but today it give me an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not why change but there is a new [commit](https://github.com/angular/devkit/commit/88a3e309e747835410ce7b909823fb263ca37d1c) to the package that rename the some aliases and produces this bug in your project look for the file

```
node_modules/@schematics/angular/component/schema.json
```

in this look the ChangeDetection Category and change the alias property from c to cd for example an try again.

```
"changeDetection": {
            "description": "Specifies the change detection strategy.",
            "enum": ["Default", "OnPush"],
            "type": "string",
            "default": "Default",
            "alias": "cd"
        },
```

With this I'm capable to run **ng g c Home or ng generate component Home** again.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This doesn't help me. After I edited the `schema.json`, I get an error, `Error: Could not find (undefined)`. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 2):

Changing the schema.json as suggested by the answer, didn't work for me. I'm using a globally installed angular cli @1.7.4. Since this issue seems to be caused by @schematics/angular (v0.7.5 in my case), I uninstalled this package from my projects dependencies

```
npm uninstall @schematics/angular --save
```

Afterwards, `ng generate component` worked for me.